# Why use i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i)) instead of (int) (Math.random() * n)?

Tags: java, arrays, math

I'm currently going through the book Computer Science: An Interdisciplinary Approach, which contains a code snippet for shuffling an array (in this example, the array contains a deck of cards). The code is as follows:

```
int n = deck.length; 
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
    int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i)); 
    String temp = deck[i]; 
    deck[i] = deck[r]; 
    deck[r] = temp; 
}
```

My question is, why is the simpler `(int) (Math.random() * n)` not preferred? Is it less random than `i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i))`?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: type casting to int will make sure the random number is always int and not any other type.

Comment: The first time you choose, you choose randomly between 52 integers.  The second time, since you multiply by `(n-1)`, you're choosing between 51 integers; the third time, between 50 integers, and so on.  This is what you need when creating a random deck.  Once you randomly pick your first card, you only have 51 choices for the second card, 50 for the third card, and so on.  This gives you 52*51*50*...*1 = 52! possibilities (the correct answer), instead of 52*52*...*52 = 52**52 possibilities (which is incorrect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They give you different values.

`(int) (Math.random() * n)` gives you a value in the range `0 <= r < n` (between `0` [inclusive] and `n` [exclusive]).

`i + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i))` gives you a value in the range **`i`**`<= r < n` (between **`i`** [inclusive] and `n` [exclusive]).

So for example, if `i` is `10`, your "simplified" version could give you `5`. The version in the code cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply T.J., I see what you're saying. Could you elaborate on why selecting a value between `i` and `n` is preferred over a value between `0` and `n`, as both seem to randomly shuffle the array? That's actually what I'm most confused about.

Comment: @user7392686 It's not a matter of _preferred_--it's a matter of _mathematically correct_.  Doing it the way you suggests gives you incorrect results.

Comment: @user7392686: You'd have to ask the author of the code. But using `i <= r < n` inside the loop does ensure that at some point it picks a value throughout the array, which using `0 <= r < n` doesn't (it could always pick something toward the front).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks, that's a very clear way to explain it!

Answer (score -1):

The idea is to take a random value that hasn't been chosen yet. If you'd allow your scheme then some elements may never get shuffled and the chance that some elements stay in place is therefore too high.

Comment: Ahhhh gotcha. Makes total sense. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Actually, I'm a little confused again. It seems that all elements will get shuffled because of `deck[i] = deck[r]`; the loop systematically goes through each element and shuffles it. In this case, is there still a reason my scheme is incorrect?

Comment: @user7392686 Yes.  It does not make all of the 52! possible results equally likely.  Off the top of my head, I'd say that decks in which the cards at the right end of the array don't move from their original position will happen much more often than if the shuffle were truly random.

Comment: @ajb: Thanks for all the mathematical explanations, it's very helpful!

Answer (score -2):

Math.Random() can return a double value between 0.0 and 1.0.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()

So if you just do (int) (Math.random() * n) then the value of r can be higher then n-1 while will lead to ArrayIndexoutofbound exception.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: Sorry, (1) you've missed the point of the question and (2) `Math.Random()` cannot return 1.0, and thus `Math.random()*n` will always be less than `n` and thus truncate to a value that is at most `n-1`.

Comment: ajb, my first statement states that Math.Random returns value between 0-1. Also second statement states that value of r can be higher then n-1. I don't know why -2.

Comment: Because your second statement is _wrong_.  Since `Math.random()` always returns a value < 1, `Math.random()*n` always returns a value < `n`.  Casting to `(int)` truncates (rounds downward), and since the argument is < `n`, the result can _never_ be higher than `n-1`.  Multiplying by `n-i` and then adding `i`, as is done in the original question, still has the same result, i.e. the result can never be higher than `n-1`.   If you still believe that `r` can be higher than `n-1`, please explain why.

Comment: Thanks ajb I ment that r can be out of bounds and that what I stated but may be I should have been more clear, will do that next time.

Comment: That's what I thought you meant.  It's still wrong.  `r` cannot be out of bounds.

Comment: ajb, if the code for r = i + + (int) (Math.random() * (n-i)); is replaced with r = i+ (int) (Math.random() * n); then r may be higher then n-1 and hence out of bounds.

Comment: You misunderstood the question.  Nobody is suggesting using `i + (int) (Math.random() * n)`.  Read the title of the question carefully.